# How to get Stream from ImageSource object for saving in Pictures Library? (Windows Phone 7, C#)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna, stream

I have an `ImageSource` object (or possibly a `BitmapImage` object). I want to save this to the Pictures Library, using the `SavePicture` method of `MediaLibrary` class (XNA framework). How can I achieve this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769549(VS.92).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [WritableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) and encode the bitmap with the `SaveJpeg` method, then use the stream you saved the image to as a parameter to MediaLibrary. Don't forget to set the position to 0 if you're using a `MemoryStream`.

A full example of this is available at msdn, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769549(VS.92).aspx